# How to avoid deadlock while updating a table multiple times in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-deadlocks

I have a stored procedure in which I am updating a table multiple times, but this is causing deadlock in my case when multiple sessions run this procedure.

I have tried to use Begin Trans and Commit statements but not working for me. I have read that creating index can solve my problem but how is it going to help and on which column should I create (which type of) index?

```
UPDATE lessonPlanSkill SET 
  PreviousProficiency = lessonPlanSkill.CurrentProficiency ,
  PreviousAccuracy = lessonPlanSkill.CurrentAccuracy  ,
  CoveragePercentage = Calculations.CoveragePercentage,
  AccuracyPercentage = Calculations.AccuracyPercentage,
  CurrentAccuracy = Calculations.AccuracyPercentage,
  TotalQuestions = Calculations.AttemptedQuestions,
  CorrectQuestions = Calculations.CorrectAttempts,
  CurrentAchievementScore = Calculations.CurrentAchievedScore,
  TotalAchievementScore = Calculations.TotalAchievementScore,
  TimeSpentInMin=TimeSpentInMin+@ModuleAttemptHistoryTimeSpent,
  AchievementPercentage = CASE WHEN (Calculations.TotalAchievementScore>0) 
  THEN (Calculations.CurrentAchievedScore/Calculations.TotalAchievementScore)*100 
  END
FROM #tblLearnerProficiency Calculations 
INNER JOIN dbo.UserLessonPlanSkill lessonPlanSkill ON lessonPlanSkill.UserId = @pUserId AND lessonPlanSkill.LessonPlanSharedTrackingId = @LessonPlanSharedTrackingId AND lessonPlanSkill.SkillId = Calculations.SkillId AND lessonPlanSkill.IsDeleted = 0

-- Insert statement to insert some data in UserLessonPlanSkill table
-- Again update statement which is most likely causing deadlock with above update statement
UPDATE lessonPlanSkill SET 
  CurrentProficiency = ISNULL(logic.ProficiencyLevel,1),
  ModifiedOn = GETUTCDATE(),
  IsSkillStuck = CASE WHEN (logic.ProficiencyLevel = @PROFICIENT_STATUS) THEN 0 ELSE IsSkillStuck END  
FROM #tblLearnerProficiency Calculations 
INNER JOIN dbo.UserLessonPlanSkill lessonPlanSkill ON 
lessonPlanSkill.UserId = @pUserId AND 
lessonPlanSkill.LessonPlanSharedTrackingId = @LessonPlanSharedTrackingId 
AND lessonPlanSkill.SkillId = Calculations.SkillId AND 
lessonPlanSkill.IsDeleted = 0
INNER JOIN dbo.JudgementLogic logic WITH(NOLOCK) ON logic.FormulaId = 
Calculations.FormulaId AND logic.IsDeleted = 0
WHERE 
Calculations.AccuracyPercentage BETWEEN AccuracyMinPercentage AND 
AccuracyMaxPercentage  AND
Calculations.CoveragePercentage BETWEEN CoverageMinPercentage AND 
CoverageMaxPercentage 

-- After some queries, another update statement comes at the end of this stored procedure updating same table.

UPDATE CurrentResult SET 
  MedianPercentage = ((CoveragePercentage/MaxQuestionCount)*AccuracyPercentage)
FROM dbo.UserLessonPlanSkill CurrentResult  
INNER JOIN #tblFilteredSkills skills ON skills.SkillId = 
CurrentResult.SkillId 
AND CurrentResult.LessonPlanSharedTrackingId = @LessonPlanSharedTrackingId
AND CurrentResult.UserId = @pUserId 
AND CurrentResult.IsDeleted = 0
```

PS: Here is the [deadlock graph](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i5BxLT7huDC1MkUbu9uZQ_PGKOfcpvGB/view) and here is [description](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldt2jDmkKAfRjdLv0IQVodFXoJNFyQRT/view) extracted from profiler

Comment: Can I avoid deadlock without creating any index because indexing can make my updates slower which I really don't want.

Comment: How come the begin transaction and commit does not work for you?  Could you elaborate on that?  Transactions were created to avoid deadlocks, therefore they will work.  You have to understand them, even with transactions only one DML can be run at one time - exclusive write!

Comment: I added Begin Transaction and Commit for first two update statements i.e. `Begin Trans First UpdateStatement SecondUpdateStatement Commit`. It worked for 4 multiple sessions concurrently accessing this procedure however, when I make the number of session upto 20, it again threw exceptions for deadlock

Comment: Should I write each update statement enclosing in `Begin Trans` and `Commit Trans`?

Comment: Well that is why I wrote that you should know how the transactions work, before actuallay using them,  I'll show you in answer.

Comment: Indexes are completely different topic and should not be (ab)used in this scenario.

Comment: Deadlocks are a massive subject, and there is not just one answer. Indexes can definitely help because they are allow much faster accessing of the relevant data. And unless you have lots of indexes on a table you shouldn't be afraid to add a few more. SQL Server is a high performance database, it can handle updating a few indexes. Transactions on the other hand do very little to avoid deadlocks, unless you take exclusive table locks on the tables you are using, and that will definitely kill your performance.

Comment: Deadlocks occurs (mostly) due to inconsistent table access where locks are obtained on the same resources via 2 different sessions, in the opposite order. SQL Server generates a deadlock graph for each deadlock which you can query and that tells you exactly what has caused the deadlock, which is usually a good start to being able to resolve it.

Comment: In many large database systems deadlocks are unavoidable, so they need to be worked around either with retries or serialisationation i.e. not allowing multiple sessions to run concurrently. But these are last resorts - a well designed database should be able to minimise deadlocks.

Comment: I recommend doing some reading, because deadlocks are not a single question/answer, they are an entire topic with many different facets https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-a-sql-server-deadlock/

Comment: @Sham, performance and concurrency (e.g. deadlocks) are closely related. Query and index tuning are the first step to avoid deadlocks. When queries touch more data than needed (e.g. due to lack of useful indexes or non-sargable expressions), deadlocks are more likely. In short, useful indexes may improve overall performance and reduce/eliminate deadlocks despite the additional overhead.

Comment: @DaleBurrell and #DanGuzman, Thank you for the useful talk, it is clearing the broader picture but I am still having same problem, can you please help me identify which will be the best possible solution or if indexing is required, which column will be the best candidate for indexing.

Comment: @Sham, I would start with the JOIN/WHERE clause columsn. A composite index on UserId, LessonPlanSharedTrackingId, SkillId, IsDeleted will be useful. If this is unique, declare it so.

Comment: Extract and post the [deadlock graph](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/01/09/sql-server-get-historical-deadlock-information-system-health-extended-events/)

Comment: I would actually recommend moving this to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DaleBurrell sure! here is the graph
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i5BxLT7huDC1MkUbu9uZQ_PGKOfcpvGB/view)
and here is description extracted from profiler
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldt2jDmkKAfRjdLv0IQVodFXoJNFyQRT/view)

Comment: Please [edit] new information into the question.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2008/09/24/todays-annoyingly-unwieldy-term-intra-query-parallel-thread-deadlocks/

Comment: Depending on how many records are in `UserLessonPlanSkill`, a filtered index on `UserId`, `LessonPlanSharedTrackingId`, `SkillId`, with a filter of `IsDeleted=0` may considerably speed up your update, thereby reducing the likelihood of deadlocks. Yes indexes add work but an appropriate index also drastically redices the amount of work required and the net effect is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by creating a temporary table, inserting required data and updating that temp table or inserting new data into that temp table. Eventually insert/update the actual table with the values in temp table on the basis of primary key (index). This resolved my deadlock issue. 
PS: Please comment or add new answer if anyone gets something better!!